# Too much cycles

Tags: optimization, x86

I consider an example from Optimizing Assembly from Agner Fog. He tests :

### Example 12.6b.  DAXPY algorithm, 32-bit mode

```
L1:
    movapd xmm1, [esi+eax]   ; X[i], X[i+1]
    mulpd  xmm1, xmm2        ; X[i] * DA, X[i+1] * DA
    movapd xmm0, [edi+eax]   ; Y[i], Y[i+1]
    subpd  xmm0, xmm1        ; Y[i]-X[i]*DA, Y[i+1]-X[i+1]*DA
    movapd [edi+eax], xmm0   ; Store result
    add eax, 16              ; Add size of two elements to index
    cmp eax, ecx             ; Compare with n*8
    jl L1                    ; Loop back
```

and he estimates ~6 cycle/iteration on Pentium M. I tried to make the same but on my CPU- Ivy Bridge. And I achieved 3 cycle per iteration but from my computations on paper it is possible to get 2 cycles. And I don't know if I made mistake in theorethical computations or it can be improved.

What I did:

[image]

From http://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/5/ I know that my CPU can retire 4 microops for cycle so it is not a bottleneck.

```
#uops fused = 8 / 4 = 2
```

So `2` is a current our bottleneck. Let's see another possibilites:

Microps have pattern: 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 and according to Agner Fog my CPU has pattern 1-1-1-1 ( and others). From that we can see that it is possible to decode instructions in 2 cycle. It is no bottleneck. Moreover, SnB cpus have microcache so neither fetching nor decoding should be the bottleneck.

Size of instruction in bytes is 32 so it fit into micro-cache window ( 32 bytes).

From my experiments, when I add `nop` instruction it increase number of cycle per iteratrion ( approx 0.5 cycle).

So, the question is:

Where is that ONE cycle? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're not limited by memory bandwidth?  You need to **test with arrays that fit in L1 cache**, because you're depending on two loads and one store per 2 clocks.  (That's more than half of IvB's theoretical max of two 128b memory ops per clock, with at most one of them being a store.)

---

Decoding can't be relevant because your loop fits in the loop buffer.  (It's less than 28 uops).  So it just issues in groups of 4 already-decoded uops.

---

Your fused-domain uop counts are wrong.  `cmp/jl` can macro-fuse into one compare-and-branch uop.  However, that mistake is balanced by another mistake due something that's not in Agner Fog's guide (yet).

`movapd [edi+eax], xmm0` can't micro-fuse on IvB, so it's 2 fused-domain uops.

[SnB-family CPUs can only micro-fuse memory operands that don't use an index register.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes)  I recently found official confirmation in Intel's optimization manual that explains the different results from Agner's testing vs. my testing: such addressing modes can micro-fuse in the decoders and uop cache, but not in the OOO core.  (See my answer on that question.  I should send Agner another message to let him know that Intel's docs sorted out our confusion...)

Try this:

```
    add    ecx, edi          ; end-of-Y pointer
    sub    esi, edi          ; esi = X-Y
L1:
    movapd xmm1, [esi+edi]   ; 1 uop
    mulpd  xmm1, xmm2        ; 1 uop
    movapd xmm0, [edi]       ; 1 uop
    subpd  xmm0, xmm1        ; 1 uop
    movapd [edi], xmm0       ; 1 micro-fused uop
    add edi, 16              ; 1 uop
    cmp edi, ecx             ; loop while (dst < end_Y)
    jb L1                    ; cmp+jb = 1 macro-fused uop
```

Loads don't need to micro-fuse, but stores are 2 fused-domain uops.  (store-address and store-data).

[IACA](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-architecture-code-analyzer) would have told you that the store was 2 uops and couldn't micro-fuse.  It's worth having a look at.  Sometimes its numbers are wrong (e.g. it thinks `shrd` is still slow on SnB), but often it's useful as long as you realize it's a simplistic approximation to the real hardware behaviour, and *not* a cycle-accurate simulator.

---

My version is 7 total fused-domain uops.  So it should run at one iteration per 2 clocks on SnB-family CPUs.  Your original was 8 uops, **so this change shouldn't make any difference**.  I wrote it before noticing that you didn't account for macro-fusion of the cmp/jcc, so I was thinking your loop was actually 9 uops.  Since adding a single `nop` slows your code down, that's additional evidence that it's 8 fused-domain uops.  If cache misses from testing with arrays too large doesn't explain it, then maybe IvB is doing badly at scheduling the load/store uops somehow?  Seems unlikely, since they all must use port 2 or 3 for store-address or load uops.  (In the unfused domain, store-data uops go to port4).

Are you sure you really got one iteration per 3 cycles with your loop?  It doesn't make sense that adding a `nop` could slow it down beyond that, because a 9 uop loop should issue in 3 cycles.

Comment: 1. Thanks! :) 
2. You obviously right. I tested my code on 2048 and 4096 array elements ( so it fits into L1) and I take ~2cycle per iteration in fact. 
3. "If cache misses from testing with arrays too large doesn't explain it, " They explain it indeed- When I make bigger array it increases a number of cycles per iteration.

4. I still have a problem what does it exactly mean that uops are fused. I know what does it mean literally- Some of uops are joined. But how?

Comment: Agner Fog's microarch guide and Intel's optimization manual should have a decent explanation of uop micro and macro fusion.  In Agner Fog's microarch pdf, he goes into more detail about fusion when describing it for the first CPU to implement it: Pentium M.  See page 90/91: "Section 7.6 Micro-op fusion" is about 2 pages long.  I'm not trying to reproduce complete explanations for everything in every answer, that would take forever.  That's why I just linked to my other answer about micro-fusion of indexed addressing modes on SnB-family CPUs.  Of course you need to read the link.

Comment: Thanks. I don't ask you to explain me everything. Links, other reference are fine.